# Need help in extracting year from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, list, date, dictionary

I was able to extract some data with below code but I wanted include year along with month in the below extracted data. Sample data looks like below. Looking for a bifurcation based on date in the data.

```
people = [
{"name": "Tom", "age": 10, "city": "NewYork", "Date": '01/01/2021'},
{"name": "Mark", "age": 5, "country": "Japan", "Date": '05/01/2021'},
{"name": "Pam", "age": 7, "city": "London", "Date": '03/06/2021'},
{"name": "Tom", "hight": 163, "city": "California", "Date": '04/06/2021'},
{"name": "Lena", "weight": 45, "country": "Italy", "Date": '12/12/2020'},
{"name": "Ben", "age": 17, "city": "Colombo", "Date": '11/12/2020'},
{"name": "Lena", "gender": "Female", "country": "Italy", "Date": '8/01/2020'},
{"name": "Ben", "gender": "Male", "city": "Colombo", "Date": '7/01/2020'},
{"name": "Tom", "age": 10, "country": "Italy", "Date": '01/01/2021'},
{"name": "Mark", "age": 5, "country": "Japan", "Date": '05/01/2021'},
{"name": "Tom", "age": 7, "city": "London", "Date": '03/06/2021'},
{"name": "Tom", "hight": 163, "country": "Japan", "Date": '04/06/2021'}
]

def groupby( fld ):
    vals = { fld: 0 }
    for row in people:
        if fld in row:
            vals[fld] += 1
            if row[fld] not in vals:
                vals[row[fld]] = 1
            else:
                vals[row[fld]] += 1
    return vals

months = 
('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec')
def groupbydate( fld ):
    vals = {}
    for row in people:
        if fld in row and 'Date' in row:
            month = months[int(row['Date'].lstrip('0').split('/')[0])-1]
            if row[fld] not in vals:
                vals[row[fld]] = {}
            if month not in vals[row[fld]]:
                vals[row[fld]][month] = 1
            else:
                vals[row[fld]][month] += 1
    return vals

print( groupby( 'name' ) )
print( groupby( 'city' ) )
print( groupby( 'country' ) )
print( )
print( groupbydate( 'city' ) )
```

Present Output

```
{'name': 12, 'Tom': 5, 'Mark': 2, 'Pam': 1, 'Lena': 2, 'Ben': 2}
{'city': 6, 'NewYork': 1, 'London': 2, 'California': 1, 'Colombo': 2}
{'country': 6, 'Japan': 3, 'Italy': 3}

{'NewYork': {'Jan': 1}, 'London': {'Mar': 2}, 'California': {'Apr': 
1}, 'Colombo': {'Nov': 1, 'Jul': 1}}
```

Wanted output as

```
{'NewYork': {'Jan 21': 1}, 'London': {'Mar 20': 2}, 'California': 
{'Apr 20': 1}, 'Colombo': {'Nov 20': 1, 'Jul 20': 1}}
```

Comment: Desired output does not match sample data - e.g. `Nov 19`, `Jul 19` are not present in your sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(people)
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%b %y')
out=pd.crosstab(df['Date'],df['city']).rename_axis(columns=None)
```

Finally:

```
d1=df['name'].value_counts().to_dict()
d1['name']=len(df)
d2=df['city'].value_counts().to_dict()
d2['city']=df['city'].value_counts().sum()
d3=df['country'].value_counts().to_dict()
d3['country']=df['country'].value_counts().sum()
d4=out.apply(lambda x:dict(x[x.ne(0)])).to_dict()
```

output:

```
print(d1)
#output
{'Tom': 5, 'Lena': 2, 'Ben': 2, 'Mark': 2, 'Pam': 1, 'name': 12}

print(d2)
#output
{'London': 2, 'Colombo': 2, 'NewYork': 1, 'California': 1, 'city': 6}

print(d3)
#output
{'Japan': 3, 'Italy': 3, 'country': 6}

print(d4)
#output

{'California': {'Apr 21': 1},
 'Colombo': {'Jul 20': 1, 'Nov 20': 1},
 'London': {'Mar 21': 2},
 'NewYork': {'Jan 21': 1}}
```

Comment: I want these values along with year corresponding to "Name" as I have in the code

Comment: @Sherlock updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: @Sherlock If your problem is solved then you can try considering accepting this as an answer...Thanks **:)**

Answer (score 1):

You can convert these dates into DateTime objects and then format them according to your needs.

```
from datetime import datetime
for record in people:
   record["Date"] = datetime.strptime(record["Date"], "%m/%d/%Y")
```

and then you can make it into month year as record["Date"].strftime("%b %y")
which will give you the `MMM YY` format.

Optional:
One of the observations is that you want to perform group by, so what you can do is use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(people)
def groupby_date(fld):
   df.groupby(by=fld, sort=False).apply(lambda group: group.groupby(by="Date").apply(len))
   result = dict()
   for (fld, date), count in x.items():
      date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
      result[fld] = {date.strftime("%b %y"): count}
   return result
```

The output would be:

```
{'NewYork': {'Jan 21': 1},
 'London': {'Mar 21': 2},
 'California': {'Apr 21': 1},
 'Colombo': {'Jul 20': 1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the date string into the date time object and then format them as per your needs.

Look at this codes which is quite similar to the code you submitted.

```
def groupbydate( fld ):
        vals = {}
        for row in people:
            if fld in row and 'Date' in row:
                datestring=row['Date']
                dt = datetime.strptime(datestring, '%m/%d/%Y')
                month = dt.strftime("%b %y")
                print(month)
                if row[fld] not in vals:
                    vals[row[fld]] = {}
                if month not in vals[row[fld]]:
                    vals[row[fld]][month] = 1
                else:
                    vals[row[fld]][month] += 1
        return vals
```